# Wordpress Customazation API section in section

Tags: themes, theme-customizer, wp-api, settings-api

Heyo,

I'm once again stuck with my Customizer API. How can I put my sections together in another Section/Folder (however you wana call it)? Like the standard Widget section:

[image: Main Section Area]
[image: Second Section Area]

I have searched for this question/problem but haven't found anything.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a Panel, the customizer contains three layers: `panels` contain sections, `sections` contain settings, and `settings` are the data that gets managed by the `controls` in the customizer UI.

```
[panel]  
  |--[section]  
  |      |--[setting] and his [control]
  |      |--[setting] and his [control]
  |--[section]  
  |      |--[setting] and his [control]
  |      |--[setting] and his [control]
```

[Panel](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_manager/add_panel/), [Section](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_manager/add_section/), [Setting](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_manager/add_setting/), [Control](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_manager/add_control/)

Create a `Panel` and when creating the `Sections` pass the `$id` of the Panel to group them in the same `Panel`.

Comment: And the Panel level is optional. If a section does not indicate a panel, then the section appears at the root. There is currently no mechanism for nesting panels inside other panels, so if you want to go more than 3-levels deep, a control would need to have its own nested UI such as is done with widgets and nav menu items.